# How correctly call multiple functions ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I would like to explain my problem of the day.

currently, I have 2 functions that work proper

I wish I could have both functions on one button

When they are separated the functions work correctly, my problem and when I try to pass them on a single button I have an error that appears
"Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined"

How can I fix this issue?thx all

make room for the code

my first function

```
putBack = (e, id) => {
e.preventDefault();
const config = {
  method: "PUT",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ id: id, livree: new Date().toISOString().slice(11, 16)}),
};
const url = entrypoint + "/alluserpls";
fetch(url, config)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(res => {
if (res.error) {
alert(res.error);
} else {
alert(`ajouté avec l'ID ${res}!`);
}
}).catch(e => {
console.error(e);
}).finally(() => this.setState({ redirect: true })); }
```

my second function

```
onChange = (id, status) => {
const validatedorder = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("validated-order") || "{}");
localStorage.setItem("validated-order", JSON.stringify({ ...validatedorder, [id]: status }))

this.setState({ color: 'red' });
this.setState({ title: 'Confirmer la livraison' });

console.log('cliqué pour preparation')
this.setState({
  statut :'preparation',
  id,
});
}
```

my multiple functions

```
megaTryMulti(e){
e.preventDefault();
this.putBack();
this.onChange();
}
```

function separate. (that work )

```
<form onSubmit={(e) => this.putBack(e, datass.id)}>
   <button type="submit">PUT</button>
</form>
```

second function separate (that work)

```
<Button style={{ backgroundColor: status === undefined || status === false ? "red" : "#4DD5C7" }} disabled={status === false} onClick={() => this.onChange(datass.id, !status)} className="buttonForLancerMaybe">{status === undefined ? "Lancer" : status === true ? "Confirmer la livraison" : "SERVI"}</Button>
```

multi function ( that is my problem and she don't works )

```
  <form onSubmit={(e) => this.megaTryMulti(e)}>  
     <Button type="submit">test</Button>
   </form>
```

Comment: Both of your functions expect arguments, megaTryMulti isn't passing any. This isn't a React problem or even specific to JavaScript; if you want functions to work correctly you need to pass in the things that they require.

Comment: @jonrsharpe 
could you give me more explanation, if my function works alone? what am i missing so that it works in multi?

Comment: You're missing *the arguments to those functions*. Compare how you're calling them in megaTryMulti to how you call them when they work.

Comment: @jonrsharpe 
are you talking about that? or nothing to see?          <Button type submit style={{ backgroundColor: status === undefined || status === false ? "red" : "#4DD5C7" }} disabled={status === false} className="buttonForLancerMaybe">{status === undefined ? "Lancer" : status === true ? "Confirmer la livraison" : "SERVI"}</Button>

Comment: Well what you've posted there doesn't call either of those functions, so what do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass all the arguments that `putBack` and `onChange` expect to receive to `megaTryMulti`, to be passed on. `putBack` takes the form onSubmit event and an id, and `onChange` takes the same id and a status

```
megaTryMulti(e, datass, status){
  e.preventDefault();
  this.putBack(e, datass.id);
  this.onChange(datass.id, !status);
}
```

Usage:

```
<form onSubmit={(e) => this.megaTryMulti(e, datass, status)}>  
  <Button type="submit">test</Button>
</form>
```